# Gnome Control Center takes forever to start and then I can't edit network settings (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, configuration

I have problem with gnome-control-center, it takes forever to start (30 seconds), and then I can't edit the network settings.

There is some clue in the verbose output:

```
$ gnome-control-center -v

(gnome-control-center:4131): libnm-WARNING **: 15:04:54.935: Unable to get permissions: Timeout was reached

** (gnome-control-center:4131): DEBUG: 15:04:54.941: Enabling debugging
```

However I have no idea where it is trying to get the permissions from?

Comment: Temporarily create a new account, and see whether Control Center also there refuses to start. If yes, you have to look for a system wide issue. If no, which I expect, then you have a problem in your current user configuration. Indeed there may be a connection to your network connectivity. However, apparently your network is currently functioning well.

Comment: The problem seems to be `nscd`, as I'm trying to configure ldap authentication, when `nscd` is configured not to cache group db, then I see this behavior , when I enable cache for group, it works ok.

Comment: Would be good to add any information that you think can help identifying the problem to the question. Use "Edit". Comments are not necessarily read and can disappear.